# How can an extension icon be seen in the activity bar only when an extension is executed in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I use a docker, but i don't always use it.

so, i want extension icon to be hidden when not in use and visible when using it.

cmake works in that way.

what should i do?

thanks.

[image: docker icon]

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues Ask its developers.

Comment: and you don't complain about the `Remote` icon?

Comment: @rioV8 but, remote is okay. because wsl, ssh also used and containers are already included in remote.

Comment: Yes but the Remote icon is also visible when you don't use it, the (Python) Test icon is only visible when my workspace has Python test enabled and there are tests found, The code of that extension is public so you can find out how they do it. The view has a name so it can be searched for